# Cant find SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to revert a site that has SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch installed to install 8788v2 patch. But the 1533 patch has been removed and I cant seem to find it anywhere.

How can I revert this patch to install 8788v2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here : https://www.wagento.com/blog/new-supee-8788-v3-patch-available-for-enterprise-edition-1-13-0-x

They say : "You can find SUPEE-1533 in the “Security Patches – October 2014” folder and SUPEE-3941 in the “Security Patches – August 2014” folder in [MyAccount](http://email2.magento.com/eq0nRD02000GGH0453qXt0s). More detailed installation instructions are available in [DevDocs](http://email2.magento.com/Y0s5H0rqt004n002XGG0SD3)."